# Visual Studio doesn't show output when using wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, ostream

I tried to print a debug message using `cout` but I am not getting any output although my app is running.

I am using the `IMPLEMENT_APP` macro.

Here is the code I tried to print some information:

```
std::cout << display->GetGeometry().GetSize().GetWidth() << " " << display->GetGeometry().GetSize().GetHeight();
```

Can someone help me understand why am I not getting the output?

I am using Visual Studio 2022.

This is the only output I get when I build & run the program:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: VideoEditor, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>App.cpp
1>VideoEditor.vcxproj -> D:\C++\VideoEditor\x64\Debug\VideoEditor.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Because `std::cout` doesn't write to the debug console. Use `OutputDebugString` instead.

Comment: @nokla, use wxLogDebug instead.